# How to fast up databases queries, when thousands of entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, query-performance

For learning php and codeigniter, i've started to create test website... something like blog. ut that's not the point.
I'm using codeigniter pagination to show all my blog's posts. but... it's starting to slow down when my database table (posts) has over 14k entries.... And I don't need answer like: "if it's blog and you'll never write so much posts then just don't think about that"... I need real solution of how to faster all this stuff.

Here's controller:

```
    function all()
{
    // Pagination $config
    $config = $this->m_posts->getPaginationConfig('all', $this->m_posts->getPostsCount());
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['posts'] = $this->m_posts->getAllPosts($config['per_page'], $page);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->template->build('posts/posts', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
    function getPaginationConfig($base_url, $total_rows)
{
    $config['base_url']         = base_url() . 'posts/'. $base_url;
    $config['total_rows']       = $total_rows;
    // ----
    $config['per_page']         = 10;
    $config['num_links']        = 5;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['uri_segment']      = 3;
    return $config;
}
    function getPostsCount($limit)
{
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $q = $this->db->get('posts');
    return $q->num_rows();
}

function getAllPosts($limit = 0, $start = 0)
{
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $this->db->where('active', 1);
    // Get LATEST posts -> pagination
    $q = $this->db->get('posts', $limit, $start);
    $array = $q->result_array();
    $data = $this->createPostsArray($array);
    return $data;
}
    function createPostsArray($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) 
    {
        $array[$key]['usr_info']   = $this->user->getUserData($row['usr_id'], 'nickname');
        $this->load->helper('cat_helper');
        $array[$key]['cat_ids'] = explodeCategories($row['cat_ids']);
        foreach ($array[$key]['cat_ids'] as $numb => $value)
        {
            $array[$key]['categories'][$numb] = $this->getCategoryName($value);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: so where should I put these indexes??

Comment: Everything in one table with 14k records? Seriously ?
Here are some serious solutions.
Indexing, possible normalization/denormallization. :)Look into those aspects and I'm sure you won't be disappointed

Comment: Putting indexes everywhere only makes it worse, Try adding one or two on your most critical attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, change your getPostsCount function to this

```
function getPostsCount () {
      return $this->db->count_all('posts');
}
```

The way you're doing it now is wasting time/memory/cpu & code lines for nothing.

Second thing, use a left/inner join to get other data rather than throwing a bunch of queries in a foreach statement (this is WRONG).

If you still need help with joining things, show table structures to get more help.

I think this tiny change, will make big difference.

**EDIT:**

After Providing more info, here's your query with  a join to users (as it's not clear how your categories works, I am not including it).

```
function getAllPosts($limit = 0, $start = 0) {
         $q = $this->db->select('p.*, u.nickname')
                        ->from('posts p')
                        ->join('users u', 'p.user_id = u.id', 'left')
                        ->limit($limit, $start)
                        ->get();
         return $q->result_array();
 }
```

This will return posts with the nickname of the user, as for the category it's not clear how you're storing them nor what explode categories is doing, If you're storing them in comma-separated field, you can use a single query to get all categories using ->where_in('id', array_of_ids);

You'll need to go through the manual to get more help on how to do things:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Comment: ok, wait. I will edit my question... because if seriously I don't what is JOIN and how it works...

Comment: For now, just make the change I noted in my post & let me know if it's faster now.

Comment: It's a bit faster with new getPostsCount function... And i didn't understand the second thing... I updated my post

Comment: If you're storing categories in comma-separated field, you're doing it wrong it should be on a separate table to make things easier. OR as presented in my answer you can use ->where_in method pass the complete array of exploded ids, return the result so you only have 1 foreach in your view (not in both view & model).

Comment: ok tnx a lot... You helped my little project with much data :D